# what does web-login actually means and how it is implemented?

Tags: mysql, ip

Bear with me please. I am a layman in web technology and have few simple questions which need simple language answers.

When we login using a username and password on any website, what exact connection/relation is established with the website server? Is it that the server stores the IP address of the user and allows the user access to certain tables from the server database for a short span of time and the regular query to the server keeps the 'connection alive'?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Usually a script on the server side connects to the database and executes the query with predefined (in the script) credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A login system receives a set of credentials from the user, typically an identifier and a password.  It could include what is called an authentication token, which is either generated by a handheld device (so you not only have to have id and password but the token generator; it's on the equivalent of requiring both the pin and the card at an ATM), or it's generated by combining the password with something else and returning an encryption result.

The login system, once it receives the credentials, compares them to what is stored on the credential database.  In some cases the credentials are sent encrypted, such that even the login system doesn't even know what they are, all it does is determine if the encryption is correct.  This would mean that even if someone was monitoring the communication channel they could not use it to fake a login later.

Now, if the credential is valid, one of two things happens.  For a desktop application or general sign-on, the login program will transfer control to either the rest of the program (for an application), or grants access to the system (for a sign on).   When the person leaves the application or signs off the system, then everything starts over.

For a website, the login program will send the user a cookie that another part of the website can read and determine the user was authenticated and their credentials passed.  This continues until the cookie expires, or the user logs out.  If the user logs out, the website sends a new cookie that says the former cookie is expired.